# Firefox/Chrome disable search opening in a new tab

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, search, browser-tabs

When you select some text with Firefox and Chrome for that matter you can right click the highlight text and search

```
some query
(highlight the text above and right click)
Search Google for "some query"
```

How can I stop it from opening in the new tab. I cannot find it in about:config or chrome://plugins

> I don't want it opened in the SAME tab. I want it opened in a NEW tab
>   but I DON'T want Firefox/Chrome to automatically switch to the new tab
>   once opened..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're referring to the internal "Search for.." of Firefox, probably there's no such option.

Well, in fact I'm surprised you want that behavior, but of course it's a matter of personal taste and work flow. But think of 'heavy' pages you're on -- when you search something and it opens in the same tab, and then you click 'Back', it will be a lot of work for the browser to re-render the page. The work flow is also different for me, because I often search not in Google, but look up words in dictionaries using [Context Search add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/pl/firefox/addon/context-search/).

There's kind of similar option [browser.search.context.loadInBackground](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Mozilla/Preferences/Preference_reference/browser.search.context.loadInBackground) recently added, saying whether to focus the new tab or not. Perhaps you should open an issue in Bugzilla.

### Alternative workaround:

Instead of right clicking and choosing 'Search in Google', you can

- make sure Google is selected as default search engine in the search field you have in top-right of the browser,
- set `browser.search.openintab` to `false` (this affects only search from the search field),
- select the text,
- drag it from the page onto the search field of the Firefox.

That way you'll have it opened in the same tab.

Comment: I don't want it opened in the SAME tab. I want it opened in a NEW tab but I don't want Firefox to automatically switch to the new tab once opened..

Comment: "How can I stop it from opening in the new tab" - I thought the opposite :) Set `browser.search.context.loadInBackground` = true (See the link: _true: New tab with search results will be opened in the background, focus stays on the current tab_)

Comment: Please attach link and I will mark as completed.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Mozilla/Preferences/Preference_reference/browser.search.context.loadInBackground

Answer (score -1):

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/force-background-tab/gidlfommnbibbmegmgajdbikelkdcmcl?hl=en

Someone made an extension that does it for Chrome... It may also affect other scenarios besides the right click->search load but I tested and it does load search results in a new tab but in the background :)))