# Prevent tab change on contextual "Search Google for '{selected text}'"

Tags: google-chrome

When using Chrome, it's possible to select some text, then use the right-click menu to launch a search for it in a new tab. By default, Chrome switches to the new tab.

I consistently find myself preferring to finish the original page before moving on.

Is it possible to prevent the switch to the new tab?

To avoid confusion, I mean when doing this:

[image]

Comment: [Firefox/Chrome disable search opening in a new tab](https://superuser.com/q/445278/241386), [Chrome right click: search Google for](https://superuser.com/q/1001059/241386)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hold down the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key when you click `Search Google for ...`.

That should open the search results in a new tab without losing focus of your current tab.

Comment: Thank you! That's been irritating me for a while. Now all I need to do is unlearn a few years of muscle memory...

Comment: @Basic Anytime. And that's going to be tricky.

Answer (score 1):

Google is [adamant](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=6459) for some reason that it won't provide an option for this.

rahi has already provided a workaround but these extensions (I'm sure there are many more in the same vein) might help as well:

1. [**Selection Search**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/selection-search/gipnlpdeieaidmmeaichnddnmjmcakoe):

   [image: 1]

   It provides the possibility to specify if a new tab should be opened in the background or foreground for individual search engines.
2. [**Simple = Select + Search**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/simple-select-%20-search/aagminaekdpcfimcbhknlgjmpnnnmooo):

   [image: 2]

Answer (score 0):

[Force Background Tab](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/force-background-tab/gidlfommnbibbmegmgajdbikelkdcmcl) does the job too.

With the following config, everything stays the same except when using "search google for..." (`https://www.google.com/search?q=*`), the search tab will be opened in the background:

[image]