# Chrome right click: search Google for

Tags: google-chrome, search

In Chrome /Chromium there is a context menu option to search Google for selected text which opens a new tab. Is it possible to some how do this but open the tab in the background?

Comment: [Prevent tab change on contextual "Search Google for '{selected text}'"](https://superuser.com/q/912451/241386), [Firefox/Chrome disable search opening in a new tab](https://superuser.com/q/445278/241386)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent tab change on contextual "Search Google for '{selected text}'"](https://superuser.com/questions/912451/prevent-tab-change-on-contextual-search-google-for-selected-text)

Answer (score 1):

This extension does exactly what you want.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/search-in-background-tab/fikfhablannhlgejpiklhbkonjkakodf/related?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

I've been using a chrome extension for a while and give me much more than that. You can configure the searching for whatever web site you desire.

[Selection Search Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/selection-search/gipnlpdeieaidmmeaichnddnmjmcakoe)

Any way, you can hold down the ctrl key when you click for searching as said in this post.

[Hold down Ctrl key](https://support.google.com/chrome/forum/AAAAP1KN0B08jltca5O6GU/?hl=en&gpf=%23!msg%2Fchrome%2F8jltca5O6GU%2FUdjd_w8oOdwJ&msgid=Udjd_w8oOdwJ)